# How to get only "sorrow_likelihood" attribute from face_annotations in Google Vision API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I want to get only "**sorrow_likelihood**" attribute from **face_annotations** in Google Vision
API.

```
**Error**
Face detected

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Repo\Mytrapture\web_project\web_project\test.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(response.face_annotations.sorrow_likelihood)
AttributeError: 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedCompositeCo' object has no attribute 'sorrow_likelihood'
```

**Code snippet-**

```
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
response = client.annotate_image({
                        'image': {
                            'source': {
                                'image_uri': url
                            }
                        }
                        })

f = "face_annotations"
if f in str(response):
    print("Face detected")
    print(response.face_annotations.sorrow_likelihood)
else:
    print("Face not detected")
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a syntax error in this line:

```py
print(response.face_annotations.sorrow_likelihood)
```

If you want to get the **sorrow_likelihood** value, you have to parse the ***face_annotations*** object because the [Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/request#:%7E:text=The%20API%20uses-,JSON,-for%20both%20requests) responses are `json` format. You may try the code below:

```py
print(response.face_annotations[0].sorrow_likelihood)
```

You can also try this below code for checking if a face is detected or not:

```py
if response.face_annotations:
    print("Face Detected")
    for data in response.face_annotations:
        print(data.sorrow_likelihood)
else:
    print("Face not detected")
```

Output if Face Detected

```
Face Detected
Likelihood.VERY_LIKELY
```